# HTML Page Select All Angular issue or NWJS issue?

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-material, nwjs

I have an issue where as I navigate around my HTML Angular app, when the page renders it renders with everything on the page "selected".

I am using the latest Angular 1.x version, along with Angular material (latest). I should add that I am running this in NWJS 0.12, which could be a factor

I have yet to identify the exact behavior pattern that makes this occur, but its often enough to be annoying to users.

Comment: Can you show some markup/code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded my version of nwjs to 0.14.7 and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let selector = document.querySelectorAll("h1");

for(let i = 0; i < selector.length; i++){

  let ng = selector[i].getAttribute("ng-model");
  
  if(ng != null){
    console.log(selector[i].classList.add("selected"))
  }
  

}
```

```css
.selected{
  background: skyblue;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1>20% Cooler</h1>
<h1 ng-model="cooler">20% Cooler</h1>
<h1 ng-model="cuteOctocat">GitHubr</h1>
```